# How to set the ActivityA TabHost fragment to other tab in ActivityB?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Actually what I tried to achieve is a "go home" button

In Activity A, I use TabHost to create the view, that means , the Tab 0 is the Home while the Tab 1- 5 is other page

The user may go to other page, and in that page, there is a button , when user click on it , it is an activityB

so , in that activityB, there is a "go home" button

```
home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
```

For that button , I can use finish() or onBackpressed() to close current activity, but how can I change the tab to tab 0 in that activityB , or , what other way can I try to achieve this?

Thanks

I make the tabhost to static but it just throw the exception like this

```
    04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1354)
04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1372)
04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:313)
04-30 09:27:06.799: E/AndroidRuntime(21154):    at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:391)
```

Comment: you having 5 tabs if you click back in second tab it should show first tab. is this correct?

Comment: Thanks fixed by using onactivityresult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you going to use tab activity,you need to use

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // on changing the page
        // make respected tab selected
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }
});
```

`setOnClickListner` is not work on tab host activity,Tab activity could find the page using `setOnPageChangeListener`